# iOS UITableView - Multiple selections from NSDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uitableview, nsdictionary

Description:

I have a UITableView that is loaded with Facebook friend json data in each row. The user will select multiple friends and the contents of their selection will fill a label on a previous page when the "done" button is pressed.

```
NSMutableArray *friends;
NSDictionary *friendsDict;
NSArray *selectedIndexes;


-viewDidLoad {

//Grab the data from Facebook and put it into an array

friends = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:jsonData[@"data"]];

}

-cellForRowAtIndexPath {   

friendsDict = friends[indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = friendsDict[@"name"];

}

-doneButtonPushed {

selectedIndexes = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];

//NOW WHAT?

}
```

Problem:

It is unclear to me what to do with the selected indexes. I know my ordered list of friends is in the "friendsDict" dictionary, but how do I get the "id" from the selected friends from the dictionary using the "selectedIndexes" array?

My failed attempt:

```
-doneButtonPushed {

selectedIndexes = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];


//this does not work
NSMutableArray *friendsArray = [friends objectsAtIndexes:selectedIndexes];

}
```

I've been scratching my head for two days over this and it's really to the point where I got pretzel in my head. I don't know how to even think about it anymore. Please help code Gods!

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with your code is that the NSArray method `objectsAtIndexes:` takes an argument of type NSIndexSet, but UITableview's `indexPathsForSelectedRows` gives you an NSArray which contains NSIndexPath objects. Here's how you can work with the NSArray:

```
- doneButtonPushed
{
  selectedIndexes = [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows];
  if (nil == selectedIndexes)
  {
    // No selection
    return;
  }

  // The documentation of indexPathsForSelectedRows talks about
  // "index-path objects" - by this it means that the objects
  // in the array have the type NSIndexPath
  for (NSIndexPath* indexPath in selectedIndexes)
  {
    // Here we get onto familiar ground :-)
    friendsDict = friends[indexPath.row];

    // I don't know the type of the "id" object, so I am just
    // using the generic type id in this example. This is just
    // a coincidence and has nothing to do with the key of
    // your dictionary being "id". If you know that the "id"
    // object is, for instance, an NSString, then change
    // the type of the variable friendId to NSString*.
    id friendId = friendsDict[@"id"];

    // Now do something with friendId ...
  }
```

Comment: @ herzbube Thanks a bunch for your suggestion. I will try this out as soon as I get home. And thank you for being incredibly descriptive. Mentioning the reason why you put the type as "id". If I were any more of a noob I would have been lost for days on that. And since i haven't tried out yet what you suggested I have no reason to doubt your accuracy. But just while it's fresh in your mind let me ask, does what you coded up there apply to multiple selections as well?

Comment: @TomTesticool Let me ask a counter question: Why do you think `indexPathsForSelectedRows` is an array and not a single `NSIndexPath` object?

Comment: @TomTesticool Yes, my code works with multiple selection (assuming you have set the table view's `allowsMultipleSelection` property to `YES`). The code is iterating over an array which can contain more than one NSIndexPath.

Comment: @ herzbube I figured it was because I was selecting multiple rows, therefore I thought it would be an array of the index numbers (int). That is probably not the case but at the time thats what I was going with. Still working on this problem, just haven't had a lot of time to work this out. If I have any more trouble I'd appreciate your input again in the future!